# How to show custom content to users coming from Facebook to Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show a custom welcome meassage to users that are coming from Facebook to my site.

How can I do it? I tried using this code (that I found here: http://themefuse.com/why-and-how-to-detect-referrer-information-in-wordpress/), but it didn’t work.

The code I’ve used:

```
$referer_parse = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); 
if(strpos($referer_parse['host'], 'google.') !== false)  
{ 
    // your PHP code
}
```

Comment: Really? Just change google to facebook. And echo something in //your PHP code ofcourse. It's not copy/paste/work you know.

Answer (score 1):

```
$referer_parse = parse_url($_SERVER[‘HTTP_REFERER’]); 
if(strpos($referer_parse[‘host’], ‘facebook.’)!==false)  
{ 
// your PHP code 
}
```